# React Bootstrap Popover in Overlay Trigger doesn't disappear when logical parent is removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using a Popover in an Overlay trigger for a delete confirmation control. The main page has a list of items and each of these items has a clickable X button that starts the deletion interaction with the user. Next the popover is displayed and the user clicks Confirm to proceed with deletion. The object is deleted and the collection view requeries for the data that should be in the list. The item that has been deleted is no longer in the list, but the popover remains visible.

This seems really strange to me because (as far as I can tell) the Overlay Trigger and Popover components are no longer being referenced in *any* render() method.

This seems somewhat similar to [react-bootstrap ModalTrigger doesn't hide when the parent element is unmounted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611583/react-bootstrap-modaltrigger-doesnt-hide-when-the-parent-element-is-unmounted) but unlike that scenario there is no use of the keys property in this case.

The relevant methods looks like ...

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <tr
        className={this.listStyles()}
      >
        {this.renderListName()}
        {this.renderOwner()}
        <td>{this.renderLastModified()}</td>
        <td>
        {this.renderButtons()}
        {this.renderProcessing()}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  },
    
  renderOverlay() {
    return (
      <OverlayTrigger
        trigger='click'
        onEntering={this.handleDeletePopoverOpened}
        onExiting={this.handleDeletePopoverClosed}
        rootClose
        placement='bottom'
        overlay={this.renderPopover()}
      >
        {this.renderDeleteButton()}
      </OverlayTrigger>
    )
  },

  renderPopover() {
    return (
      <Popover id='delete_list' title="Confirm Delete">
        <strong>Are you sure?</strong>
        <ButtonGroup bsSize='small' className='deletionGroup'>
          <Button bsStyle='danger' onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Popover>
    )
  },
```

I've tried explicitly predicating the rendering of the popover on a state and then setting that state in the componentWillUnmount method such that it should hide the popover. This (as one would expect) doesn't work either, undoubtedly because the code is never run as the render method is (correctly) not invoked.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this just a defect in React Bootsrap? Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Year-old question so I hope you figured out a solution :-)

The same issue lives on: I solved it by adding `rootClose` to my trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If the error persists ...

Use the "rootClose" accessory to make the Popover disappear simply by clicking outside.

```js
...
  <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" rootClose placement="right" overlay={popover}>
...
```

Replace the "click" trigger with the "focus" trigger .. to make it disappear by clicking on it ....

```js
...
  <OverlayTrigger trigger="focus" placement="right" overlay={popover}>
...
```

source .. [How to Dismiss a React-Bootstrap Popover on Click Outside](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-dismiss-react-bootstrap-popover-on-click-outside)